# Sqlalchemy query on multiple relationship between two tables

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I am having trouble with the following setup of a sqlalchemy ORM connected to a postgresql db.

```
class Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = "map"

    id = Column(BigInteger, Sequence(name="myseq"), primary_key=True)
    cmp_1_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("component.id"))
    cmp_2_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("component.id"))
    
class Component(Base):
    __tablename__ = "component"

    id = Column(BigInteger, Sequence(name="myseq"), primary_key=True)

    map_1 = relationship("Map", back_populates="cmp_1", foreign_keys=Map.cmp_1_id, uselist=False)
    map_2 = relationship("Map", back_populates="cmp_2", foreign_keys=Map.cmp_2_id, uselist=False)

Map.cmp_1 = relationship(
    "Component", back_populates="map_1", primaryjoin=Map.cmp_1_id == Component.id
)
Map.cmp_2 = relationship(
    "Component", back_populates="map_2", primaryjoin=Map.cmp_2_id == Component.id
)
```

Now I want to query a specific Map object, whose `cmp_1` object has a certain `"known_value"` of `other_attribute`. I tried various statements, using Query API and Select API and with a colleague finally found this solution to be working:

```
(session.query(Map.id)
    .join(Map.cmp_1)
    .where(Component.other_attribute=="known_value")
    .one()[0]
)
```

During my research on the topic I read through some other SO articles, which raised further questions. So here they come:

- My main question: why can't I do the query like this:

```
(session.query(Alias_Map_Expanded.id)
    .where(Map.cmp_1.other_attribute=="known_value")
).one()[0]
```

This raises the exception `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Map.cmp_1 has an attribute 'other_attribute'`

- More generally: how would I design the model better (as in: more robust and easier to jump between relations) to possibly be able to do the above? The relationships need to be One (Component) To Many (Map), i.e a Map object points to one to two (cmp_2 is optional) components. In turn a component can be pointed to from multiple Map rows/objects.
- Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806625/sqlalchemy-create-relations-but-without-foreign-key-constraint-in-db): <s>Should I always define a foreign key along with a relationship to not break the relationship inside the db?</s> *Update:* I removed this question because I now find it rather misleading and not really worth having it answered.
- Based on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703652/sqlalchemy-multiple-relationships-between-tables): I guess I also need to use the `post_update` to not have a circular dependency? Or do I misinterpret the use of `post_update`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After some thorough consulting of the extensive sqlalchemy docs I found some answers:

- To my first question and the related query: <s>in my ORM classes I did not specify the loading type of the data, leaving it at the default type "lazy". Therefore the `other_attribute` attribute's value is not loaded with the first query but rather it would take a second call to `query1_result.other_attribute` upon which the related content would be queried separately. Alternatively I'd need to specify an eager loading type for the proposed query to be working.</s>

  I just figured, even if I use eager-loaded queries, I still cannot filter related objects, using class-level ORM syntax, because at that point the ORM instance has not yet mapped its relative. The filtering ("where" clause) needs to be formulated on SQL level, i.e like the first example I gave above...
- There is most likely no meaningful answer to that, especially without deeper knowledge of my database structure...
- Third question, based on link: I think my question is somewhat strange and maybe even misleading. I will remove it from the original post.
- Last question, based on 2nd link: I haven't investigated so much more on this question, being it the least important to me, but I think I got the concept of post_update wrong and will not need it for my purpose.

I got all of it from sqlalchemy docs, so in case you hit that question and have a similar problem, work your way through the extensive documentation conglomeration. The answer is most likely there.